# CSS only loading if in edit mode

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout, custom

I have created a custom master page a page layout that references a custom CSS file.

**Problem:**

A problem I'm running into is that the page will load the CSS only when you are in edit mode; however, when you click save, the page returns to normal display mode and the CSS goes away.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have MDS enabled on the site?  Seems really similar to issues I've seen related to MDS.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/08bc1972-1047-4e76-91dc-3d9f2d44c2f6/jquery-only-executes-when-in-edit-mode-mds-issues?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: MDS is disabled @Nate

Comment: It sounds like you only added your master page to application pages, and not the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Is your css in layout placed within PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead placeholder in your Page Layout?

e.g.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link href="/Style Library/css/????.css" rel="stylesheet">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```